# Why does this say to 'Expected '('' to a integer in cost?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, stdvector

For example:

```
struct Spell 
{
    int id;
    vector<int> cost(4);
};
```

It says

```
'Expected parameter declaration'.
```

Also does this piece of code have a difference?

```
if (can(vector <int>inv, spell.cost)) 
{
    cout << "CAST " << spell.id << endl;
    done = true;
    break;
}
```

This one says

```
'Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction'
```

Could by any chance lend me a hand?

Comment: It's funny how everyone understands that this can't be a function because of the rvalue, just the compiler doesn't.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The compiler should understand that, too: This cannot be parsed as a function declaration, can it? The Wikipedia example for the most vexing parse id different: `int i(int(my_dbl));` is a function declaration that happens to have redundant parentheses around its parameter name. `4`, on the other hand, cannot be a function parameter declaration, so the line cannot declare  a function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the [member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) section in *cppreference.com*:

> Non - static data members may be initialized in one of two ways :
>
> 1. In the **member initializer list of the constructor**.
>
>    ```
>    struct S
>    {
>        int n;
>        std::string s;
>        S() : n(7) {} // direct-initializes n, default-initializes s
>    };
>    ```
> 2. Through **a *default member initializer*, which is a *brace* or *equals initializer* included in the member declaration** and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.
>
>    ```
>    struct S
>    {
>        int n = 7;
>        std::string s{ 'a', 'b', 'c' };
>        S() {} // default member initializer will copy-initialize n, 
>               // list-initialize s
>    };
>    ```

As per the above (emphasis mine), your member declaration is wrong.

I assume that, your intention was to have a vector of `int`s (i.e `cost`) as member and allocate `4` integers and default (value)initialize them .

You can fix it by either of the following ways:

1. <sup>✱</sup>[uniform - braced initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

   ```
   struct Spell {
       int id;
       std::vector<int> cost{ std::vector<int>(4) };
       //                  ^^^                  ^^^^
   };
   ```
2. equals initializer

   ```
   struct Spell {
       int id;
       std::vector<int> cost =  std::vector<int>(4); // or decltype(cost)(4)
       //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   };
   ```
3. provide a constructor and in constructor member initializer

   ```
   struct Spell { 
       int id; 
       std::vector<int> cost;
       Spell()
           : cost(4) // constructor member initializer
       {} 
   };
   ```

*<sup>✱</sup>Since `std::vector` [has the `std::initializer_list` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), unfortunately you can not write `std::vector<int> cost{ 4 }`, as it will be interpreted, the `4` being a single vector element.*

Comment: LOL, one gotta love C++. Most intuitive way of initializing a vector with a given size. I'd probably prefer omitting `(4)` completely over doing this, especially because the number is so small.

Comment: The alternative is to add a constructor to the struct, eg: `struct Spell { int id; std::vector<int> cost; Spell() : cost(4) {} };`

Comment: This case doesn't have anything to do with the most vexing parse, because of the literal `4` inside `()`. There's no way to parse that as a function declaration afaik. After all, how could `4` be a type?